# SMS autoinstallable

Tags: sms

How can I send a sms with net settings, like the one some providers send when you plug the sim first time?

P.S.: No hack intention! My girlfriend is anti-tech and 600 km. away. I want to send her APN settings so we could go online!

Comment: If memory serves, it requires setting up a Service center, which only providers can do. Can't they just download the settings?

Comment: Her provider don't send sms with settings. I do know the settings, but she can't handle and I don't remember her phone exact menus layout(and teamviewer work on internet only...) And that would be the ONLY internet in the area

Comment: Yeah, and team viewer can't work mobile > mobile either. Your only hope is doing the settings when you next see her.

Comment: But wat a service center has and a regular sms don't?

Comment: they can provide service messages to tweak settings. Only certain settings, don't worry. It's regulated by the SIM and the OS. Maybe with root, but if your gf is anti-tech, root is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Should be a bit in sms that say „I am a installable settings msg”. No matter the route, the data are the same - the phone can't choose

Comment: the phone can't choose? Oh boy, it can, otherwise it would be buggier than than CyanogenMod nightlies. I see what you mean though- there is probably a bit in the SMS saying "Hey! I'm not normal!" Try getting in contact with the provider- they might have a method.

Comment: No problem. Let us know how it goes.